# Cold start idle issue

Tags: toyota, camry, idle

I have a v6 Toyota Camry. During cold mornings whenever I start the car it idles very low (200-700rpm) fluctuating swiftly and almost stalling. Also lights dim whenever the idle drops quickly then the idle speed motor refs the engine to stop it from stalling.

It’s like the idle alternates from 200rpm to 700rpm up and down until the car is warm.

What would cause this?

Comment: Welcome to the site, what model year is your car?

Comment: 2003 model Camry v6

Answer (score 1):

The problem could very well be caused by the air idle control valve.  The first thing I'd do would be to clean it thoroughly with fuel system cleaning spray.  I'd also check the condition of any vacuum hoses attached to it plus check the security of any wiring attached.

Comment: Also first thing that came to mind was the idle control valve. These can be cleaned but should be treated as delicate.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck EGR(if it has one), dirty throttle body, faulty IAC valve
Does the idel improve when its warm (vacuum leak)-best way is to scan it and view fuel trims for guidance